# I found a block of javascript but do not understand what it does

Tags: javascript, html

I found a javascript but do not understand what it does.  Is this an object or any other function?

```
main : {
    //variables declaration
    var ret = "";
    var text = "";
    var tmp = "";
    var CSVString = "";
    var counter = 1;
    var page = 1;
    var header = 'TITLE|JOB_ID|RECRUITER|DESCRIPTION2|TIME';
    //if function 

    if (page === 1 ) {
            break main;
        }
}
```

Please, can anyone explain to me what happen in the if function true? break main ?

Comment: are you sure this is the code? may be it is related to ES6 syntax.. I don't know.

Comment: This looks like an invalid JavaScript. Where did you get it from?

Comment: But I fund this property standalone without in a object. Please help me.. @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: Who's this `@DontVoteMeDown`?

Comment: @SanjibDebnath Where is it getting used?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I get it from a imacro javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** After your edit, the question is *slightly* different in that you've added a [labeled `break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Using_a_labeled_break_statement). In the code posted, it is *still* redundant, but it could be used to break out of nested loops if used correctly, as seen in the linked MDN example:

> Given an array of items and an array of tests, this example determines whether all items pass all tests
>       var allPass = true;
>       var i, j;
>
> ```
> top:
> for (i = 0; items.length; i++)
>   for (j = 0; j < tests.length; i++)
>     if (!tests[j].pass(items[i])){
>       allPass = false;
>       break top;
>     }
> ```

**Original Answer:**

While perfectly valid, this is just a javascript [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) followed by a block. `main :` will do nothing and will act the same as if omitted:

```js
main : {
    //variables declaration
    var ret = "";
    var text = "";
    var tmp = "";
    var CSVString = "";
    var counter = 1;
    var page = 1;
    var header = 'TITLE|JOB_ID|RECRUITER|DESCRIPTION2|TIME';
}
alert(header);
```

Would be the same as if you wrote this:

```
{
    //variables declaration
    var ret = "";
    var text = "";
    var tmp = "";
    var CSVString = "";
    var counter = 1;
    var page = 1;
    var header = 'TITLE|JOB_ID|RECRUITER|DESCRIPTION2|TIME';
}
alert(header);
```

Label statements are intended to be used within loops, but since Javascript has no *goto* statement, it is redundant elsewhere in code.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's often the silly, easy answers you get votes for rather than the *good* ones. I've seen this so many times in questions, I really ought to have closed as duplicate....if only I could find an appropriate one!

Comment: @RGraham Silly for you but not for the upvoted users :)

Comment: I think break top (label) means reset the all things (variable) and run code from top (label), I am correct?

Comment: @SanjibDebnath No, it means break out of any nested loops between this line and where `top` was declared. It will not affect the *state* of the variables